# Change id of multiple item of array React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, jsx

I'm using React JSX with Hooks, and I have a problem. I'd like to change a p id of all the vector items when I click on one of them.
In particular:

- I have a vector and for every item of this vector I call a component:
  `cards.map((item, index) => (<Card key={index} card={item} index={index} hover={hover} /> ))}`
- Inside the Card componet I have the div tag with onClick event:  `<div onClick={TitleTransition}`>
- The TitleTransition function changes a state of click:  `function TitleTransition() { setClick(true);}`
- This is the p tag inside the Card component:  `<p id={click ? "titleTransition" : ""}>{props.card.p1}</p>`

Hence, when I click in **one** of these item (I have called them card) I'd like to change the p id for **all** the items (cards).

Anyone could help me? Thank you!

Comment: Dynamic IDs are a bad code smell, and duplicate IDs on multiple elements is invalid HTML

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, how could I do it?

Comment: Can you fix the invalid HTML first, at least?

Answer (score 0):

this is more a guess answer than anything else, but i'm unable to comment before 50 reputation.
If i had to guess, I'd say you are trying to change the styling onClick on a Card component and maybe additionally reset the styling of the other cards.
In that case you should try to use instead of the id prop of the p tag either the style or the className prop. I imagine you have a css file with something similar to

```
#titleTransition {
/* Your styling if element is clicked */
}
```

If you use the className prop, which is the React equivalent of the html class attribute, you have to change your css line to something like

```
.titleTransition {
/* Your styling if element is clicked */
}
```

or

```
  :global(.titleTransition) {
    /* Your styling if element is clicked */
    }
```

or whatever way of styling you prefer in react, there are so many.

If you want to change all Card elements, onClick you will probably have to save the dataset for the cards in a state in their parent component (where the .map(...) is used to add the  elements) and add an attribute to that data, such as 'isClicked'. Then define a function that takes the index of the  and add the function to the props of the Card, like () and call that function in the Card by adding it in the . Then use it in the :

```
<div onClick={() => props.onChildClickChangeDataState(props.index)} />
```

This will trigger the function in the parent, where you can iterate over the dataset and change the isClicked attribute to the value you like.
To change the styling you then can use

```
<p className={props.item.isClicked ? 'titleTransition' : '' />
```

This an approach that helps you changing all  at once as well as avoiding the invalid HTML @CertainPerformance mentioned.
I hope i guessed right and it helps you on the right track. It is hard to help you more at the moment. Maybe you could share the Code of you Card Parent Component, Card, your CSS file, and why you would like to change all id's at once. Then somebody might be able to help you a bit better.